# Terraform App Service wont connect to Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

In Terraform, I'm trying to get my App Service to connect to a storage account so that it can read files for the main website.

I've been following the guide on HashiCorp today: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#access_key

Here it mentions to be able to do this it has to connect via an access key, this is where it gets confusing. I found a working example here:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10435

Yet mine errors and I think its to do with the key, I first tried doing it via a customer managed key then a data source and now I'm just very confused on how to actually get this to work.

Once again the Terraform Docs are limited at best.

Here is my Code:

Website App Code:

```html
resource "azurerm_app_service" "website_app" {
  name                = var.website_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.Example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.websiteappserviceplan.id


  app_settings = {
    "KEY_VAULT_URL" = azurerm_key_vault.secrets.vault_uri

  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    dotnet_framework_version = "v5.0"
    app_command_line         = "dotnet EventManagement.Web.dll"

  }

  storage_account {
    name         = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
    type         = "AzureBlob"
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
    access_key   = data.azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
    share_name   = "guides"
    mount_path   = "/var/lib/guides"
  }

  logs {
    detailed_error_messages_enabled = true
    failed_request_tracing_enabled  = true
    application_logs {
      azure_blob_storage {
        level             = "Information"
        sas_url           = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }

    http_logs {
      azure_blob_storage {
        sas_url           = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "StorageAccount"
    type  = "Custom"
    value = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.primary_connection_string
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

```html
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_installers_account" {
  name                     = "nscwebstoredinstallersac"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.Example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.Example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  #primary_access_key       = azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key.guides_key.name 

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "website_installers_account" {
  name                = "nscwebstoredinstallersac"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "website_installers_container" {
  name                  = "${var.website_name}-installerscont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "website_installers_container_sas" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container.name


  start  = timestamp()
  expiry = time_rotating.main.rotation_rfc3339

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = true
    create = true
    write  = true
    delete = true
    list   = true
  }

  cache_control       = "max-age=5"
  content_disposition = "inline"
  content_encoding    = "deflate"
  content_language    = "en-US"
  content_type        = "application/json"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key" "guides_key" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.id
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.secrets.id
  key_name           = azurerm_key_vault_key.website_guides_key.name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
  ]
}
```

Error Message:

```html
Error: updating Storage Accounts for App Service "websitename": web.AppsClient#UpdateAzureStorageAccounts: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
```

UPDATE

I have been messing about with this all day,according to this website: https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-app-service

The Storage Name should be the identifier. Which I have changed and get a new error message that states the following:

```html
Error: updating Storage Accounts for App Service "websitename": web.AppsClient#UpdateAzureStorageAccounts: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="AzureStoragePropertyDictionary is invalid.  ID in AzureStoragePropertyDictionary contains invalid characters: /subscriptions/3b92ad75-8bb4-44a3-92df-394bc15085ef/resourceGroups/Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/nscwebstoredinstallersac" Details=[{"Message":"AzureStoragePropertyDictionary is invalid.  ID in AzureStoragePropertyDictionary contains invalid characters: /subscriptions/3b92ad75-8bb4-44a3-92df-394bc15085ef/resourceGroups/Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/nscwebstoredinstallersac"},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"51021","Message":"AzureStoragePropertyDictionary is invalid.  ID in AzureStoragePropertyDictionary contains invalid characters: /subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/Terraform/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/nscwebstoredinstallersac","MessageTemplate":"{0} is invalid.  {1}","Parameters":["AzureStoragePropertyDictionary","ID in AzureStoragePropertyDictionary contains invalid characters: /subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/Terraform/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/nscwebstoredinstallersac"]}}]
```

It sort of makes sense for the Storage Name to be the Identifier of the Storage account as why would you specify the name twice?

The storage account successfully writes its key that the web site config uses to the Key Vault so that does work. Its just the App Service just cant communicate with the storage account. Its driving me insane.

I have also done a complete destroy and reapply of the env changed my state file tried a whole new subscription. Error Still comes around.

Please see updated code bellow. Thank you.

Website Update Code:

```html
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "websiteappserviceplan" {
  name                = "website-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "website_app" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.website_installers_storage_accesspolicy,
    azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container
  ]

  name                = var.website_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.Example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.websiteappserviceplan.id


  app_settings = {
    "KEY_VAULT_URL" = azurerm_key_vault.secrets.vault_uri

  }

  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    dotnet_framework_version = "v5.0"
    app_command_line         = "dotnet EventManagement.Web.dll"

  }

  storage_account {
    name         = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.id 
    type         = "AzureBlob"
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
    access_key   = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.AccessKey.id
    share_name   = azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container.name
    mount_path   = "/var/lib/guides"
  }

  logs {
    detailed_error_messages_enabled = true
    failed_request_tracing_enabled  = true
    application_logs {
      azure_blob_storage {
        level             = "Information"
        sas_url           = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }

    http_logs {
      azure_blob_storage {
        sas_url           = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }

  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "StorageAccount"
    type  = "Custom"
    value = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.primary_connection_string
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Storage Account Update Code:

```html
resource "time_rotating" "main" {
  rotation_rfc3339 = null
  rotation_years   = 2

  triggers = {
    end_date = null
    years    = 2
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_log_storage" {
  name                     = "cicweblogsstorageacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "website_logs_container" {
  name                  = "${var.website_name}-logscont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "website_logs_container_sas" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name


  start  = timestamp()
  expiry = time_rotating.main.rotation_rfc3339

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = true
    create = true
    write  = true
    delete = true
    list   = true
  }

  cache_control       = "max-age=5"
  content_disposition = "inline"
  content_encoding    = "deflate"
  content_language    = "en-US"
  content_type        = "application/json"
}

------ RELEVANT AREA FOR PROBLEM BELLOW ---------

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_installers_account" {
  name                     = "nscwebstoredinstallersac"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  #primary_access_key       = azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key.guides_key.name 

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "website_installers_container" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account
  ]
  name                  = "${var.website_name}-installerscont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

As I am now passing the Access Key for the storage account Via Key Vault I have now included the Key Vault Code:

```html
// Users & Groups which I want to give permissions to be able to access the keyvault.
data "azuread_user" "user" {
  user_principal_name = "email"
}

data "azuread_group" "AZ_AD_Group" {
  display_name     = "email group"
  security_enabled = true
}

// This gets the Azure AD Tenant ID information to deploy for KeyVault. 
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "secrets" {
  name                       = "${var.key_vault_name}-${random_string.myrandom.id}"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = false

  #access_policy {
  #  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  #object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  #  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  # secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  #  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
  #}
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Website_Logs_Storage_URI" {
  name         = "WebsiteLogsStorageURI"
  value        = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Website_Guides_Access_key" {
  name         = "WebsiteGuidesAccessKey"
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
  ]

}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Guides_AccessKey" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container
  ]
  name         = azurerm_key_vault_secret.Website_Guides_Access_key.name
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "website_logs_key" {
  name         = "${var.website_name}-logskey"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048
  key_opts     = ["decrypt", "encrypt", "sign", "unwrapKey", "verify", "wrapKey"]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "website_guides_key" {
  name         = "${var.website_name}-guideskey"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048
  key_opts     = ["decrypt", "encrypt", "sign", "unwrapKey", "verify", "wrapKey"]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
  ]
}



resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azuread_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_AZ_AD_Group.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "service_principal" { // This is for the Service Principal in the pipeline to be able to make changes to Key Vault. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_logs_storage_accesspolicy" { // This is for the Storage Account for Website Logs. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.identity[0].principal_id
  key_permissions         = ["get", "create", "delete", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify", ]
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_installers_storage_accesspolicy" { // This is for the Storage Account for Website Logs. 
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container
  ]
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.secrets.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.identity[0].principal_id
  key_permissions         = ["get", "create", "delete", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify", ]
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}
```

Providers Used:

```html
# Terraform Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
  }
  #Terraform State Storage Account
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

# Providers Block
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id     = "VALUE"
  client_id     = "VALUE"
  client_secret = "VALUE"
}

provider "random" {}
provider "time" {}

# Random String Resource

resource "random_string" "myrandom" {
  length  = 6
  number  = false
  upper   = false
  special = false
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error message thrown and other relevant information.

Comment: Updated with Error Message was there anything else you wanted to see?

Comment: Hello @Jason, may I know if there is "guides" container present inside storage account "nscwebstoredinstallersac"?

Comment: As I see the container you have added in the code has name "${var.website_name}-installerscont"

Comment: yes is this an issue? It has named it and made the container when I applied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are giving `name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.id` in storage account block for your then it will give the below error . So , you have to give a name to it only which you want to set like `WebsiteStorageConnectionString`.

[image]

And for the second error that you get as below because we can't use Azure Blobs on Windows App Service ,It is a limitation from Microsoft end as mentioned in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-windows#limitations).So, as a solution you can use `kind = linux` in app service plan block or you can create a file share and use it with app service if you don't want to change kind.

[image]

---

**Solutions:**

1. Creating a file share instead of Container and Using AzureFiles instead of Azure blobs.

> ```
> resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_installers_account" { 
> name                     = "nscwebstoredinstallersac"  
> resource_group_name      =
> data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name  
> location                 =
> data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location 
> account_tier             = "Standard"   account_replication_type =
> "LRS"   identity {
>     type = "SystemAssigned"   } }
>
> resource "azurerm_storage_share" "website_installers_share" {   name  
> = "${var.website_name}-installersfileshare"   storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name   quota       
> = 50 }
> ```
>
> Using the file Share in Web App:
>
> ```
>   storage_account {
>     name         = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
>     type         = "AzureFiles"
>     account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
>     access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
>     share_name   = azurerm_storage_share.website_installers_share.name
>     mount_path   = "/mounts/guides"#requires to be /mounts/
>   }
> ```
>
> **Outputs:**
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

2. Change the App service from Windows to Linux if you want to use AzureBlob.

> ```
> resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "websiteappserviceplan" {  
> name = "appserviceplan-dgyn27h2dfoyojc"     
> location =
> data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location 
> resource_group_name =
> data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name   
> kind = "Linux" # only necessary when you want to set linux otherwise
> # it bydefault take windows    
> reserved = true    
> sku {
>     tier = "Standard"
>     size = "B1"    
> }  
> }
> ```
>
> And you can use the below:
>
> ```
>     storage_account {
>     name         = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
>     type         = "AzureBlob"
>     account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
>     access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
>     share_name   = azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container.name
>     mount_path   = "/var/lib/guides"
>   }
> ```
>
> **Outputs:**
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

---

**Overall Script which I used for testing :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "random"{}
provider "time" {}
resource "random_string" "myrandom" {
  length  = 6
  number  = false
  upper   = false
  special = false
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current"{}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform"{
    name="ansumantest"
}
variable "website_name" {
  default = "ansuman-app"
}

// This gets the Azure AD Tenant ID information to deploy for KeyVault. 
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "nscsecrets" {
  name                       = "${var.website_name}-${random_string.myrandom.id}"
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions  = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions     = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_accesspolicy" {
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id          = azurerm_app_service.website_app.identity[0].tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_app_service.website_app.identity[0].principal_id
  secret_permissions = ["get"]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_logs_storage_accesspolicy" { // This is for the Storage Account for Website Logs. 
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.identity[0].principal_id
  key_permissions    = ["get", "create", "delete", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify", ]
  secret_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "website_logs_key" {
  name         = "website-logs-key"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id

  key_type = "RSA"
  key_size = 2048
  key_opts = ["decrypt", "encrypt", "sign", "unwrapKey", "verify", "wrapKey", ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.website_logs_storage_accesspolicy
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_log_storage" {
  name                     = "ansumanstorageacc12345"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "website_logs_container" {
  name                  = "${var.website_name}-cont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name
}
resource "time_rotating" "main" {
  rotation_rfc3339 = null
  rotation_years   = 2

  triggers = {
    end_date = null
    years    = 2
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "website_logs_container_sas" {
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name


  start  = timestamp()
  expiry = time_rotating.main.rotation_rfc3339

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = true
    create = true
    write  = true
    delete = true
    list   = true
  }

  cache_control       = "max-age=5"
  content_disposition = "inline"
  content_encoding    = "deflate"
  content_language    = "en-US"
  content_type        = "application/json"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "website_installers_account" {
  name                     = "nscwebstoredinstallersac"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "website_installers_container" {#for linux app
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account
  ]
  name                  = "${var.website_name}-installerscont"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

/*
## This Should be used for Windows App Service instead of container
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "website_installers_share" {
  name                 = "${var.website_name}-installersfileshare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
  quota                = 50
}
*/
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "websiteappserviceplan" {
  name                = "appserviceplan-dgyn27h2dfoyojc"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  kind = "Linux" # only necessary when you want to set linux otherwise it bydefault take windows
reserved = true

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "website_app" {
  name                = var.website_name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.websiteappserviceplan.id

  app_settings = {
    "KEY_VAULT_URL"                        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.vault_uri
  }

  site_config {
  always_on = true
  dotnet_framework_version = "v5.0"
  app_command_line         = "dotnet EventManagement.Web.dll"
  
  }
  # this is for linux app
    storage_account {
    name         = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
    type         = "AzureBlob"
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
    access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
    share_name   = azurerm_storage_container.website_installers_container.name
    mount_path   = "/var/lib/guides" 
  }
  /*
  # this is for Wnidows App
  storage_account {
    name         = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
    type         = "AzureFiles"
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.name
    access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.website_installers_account.primary_access_key
    share_name   = azurerm_storage_share.website_installers_share.name
    mount_path   = "/mounts/guides" #requires to be /mounts/
  }
  */
  logs{
    detailed_error_messages_enabled = true
    failed_request_tracing_enabled = true
    application_logs {
      azure_blob_storage {
        level="Information"
        sas_url = format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }
    http_logs {
      azure_blob_storage{
        sas_url=format("https://${azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.website_logs_container.name}%s", data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.website_logs_container_sas.sas)
        retention_in_days = 365
      }
    }
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "StorageAccount"
    type  = "Custom"
    value = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.primary_connection_string
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```