# Mount BLOB Container as a directory in AppService

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

We have an Angular application running on AppService (Windows) and there are large volume of SCORM packages on BLOB storage. To launch the SCORM package, we need to iframe the launcher URL(a BLOB URL) inside an Angular component. The SCORM launcher html file has few JS method which we need to access from Angular component. When trying to access the JS method from Angular, we are getting Cross origin error.

One option is to place all the SCORM packages under the same AppService root folder so that both Angular application and SCORM packages will be under same domain. But since these SCORM packages run into hundreds of GB, it is best to place it in storage rather in root folder.

So is there any way to mount a BLOB container as a drive in AppService so that when accessing the JS methods in Angular it will not result in Cross origin error?

**Note:** We don't follow container deployment but direct deployment to AppService.

Comment: Hello , May I please know what is the os of the app service like windows or Linux ? If windows then you can only mount azure file as your app is non containerised and if Linux then both blob container and azure file can be mounted.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT yes it is Windows

Comment: thanks for the confirmation @Gopi , please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571719/terraform-app-service-wont-connect-to-storage-account/69590687#69590687) and [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-windows#limitations) for the same .

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Sure, we are working on it. Will update in a day or two.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I have already mentioned in the comment , It is not possible to mount `AzureBlob` in a App Service of `kind:Windows` , you can only use `Azure Files` as mentioned in the [`Microsoft Document in limitations section`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-windows#limitations). If it was of `kind:linux` then you could have mounted both `AzureBlobs` and `Azure Files`.

I have already tested for the same thing while creating a App service of windows and mounting the azure blob container using terraform in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571719/terraform-app-service-wont-connect-to-storage-account/69590687#69590687) and as you can find the output there it will error out.

So , as a Solution you can create a `Azure File Share` in the storage account and  mount the same in the app service.

**You can refer the below documents :**

[Create Fileshare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-portal?tabs=azure-portal)

[Mount Fileshare in Windows App Serice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-windows#mount-storage-to-windows-container)